# Reentering Datarow in DataTable

Tags: c#, datagridview, dialogresult

Hello everyone I write a code using VC#2008 to allow  the user to enter many `DataRows`  sequntially using an index to `dataTable` as he needs using yes/no dialogresult.

firstly the the user enter his data using textboxes and comboboxes using a function, then the dilodresult pops up "do you want to enter more records?" if yes clear the textboxes and call the function and plusing the `index` and show the data at datagridview ,`but it doesnot show  any data at the datagridviewand the dialogResult countinue showing without performing anything`

this the fuction code:

```
  public DataTable showout2(int index, bool bl)
    {
        DataTable dtab = new DataTable();
        DataRow row = dtab.NewRow();
        string[] newRow = new string[14];
        try
        {

            DataColumn dc1 = new DataColumn("رقم المتسلسل");
            DataColumn dc2 = new DataColumn("رقم الحساب");
            DataColumn dc3 = new DataColumn("أسم الحساب");
            DataColumn dc4 = new DataColumn("المالك");
            DataColumn dc5 = new DataColumn("تاريخ");
            DataColumn dc6 = new DataColumn("قيمة");
            DataColumn dc7 = new DataColumn("نوع العملة");
            DataColumn dc8 = new DataColumn("البيان");
            DataColumn dc9 = new DataColumn("الدائن");
            DataColumn dc10 = new DataColumn("المدين");
            DataColumn dc11 = new DataColumn(" اجمالي الدائن");
            DataColumn dc12 = new DataColumn("اجمالي المدين");
            DataColumn dc13 = new DataColumn("تفاصيل");
            DataColumn dc14 = new DataColumn("التأكيد");
            dtab.Columns.Add(dc1);
            dtab.Columns.Add(dc2);
            dtab.Columns.Add(dc3);
            dtab.Columns.Add(dc4);
            dtab.Columns.Add(dc5);
            dtab.Columns.Add(dc6);
            dtab.Columns.Add(dc7);
            dtab.Columns.Add(dc8);
            dtab.Columns.Add(dc9);
            dtab.Columns.Add(dc10);
            dtab.Columns.Add(dc11);
            dtab.Columns.Add(dc12);
            dtab.Columns.Add(dc13);
            dtab.Columns.Add(dc14);
            DateTime date = new DateTime();
            date = DateTime.Today;

            row[0] = numb.Text.ToString();
            row[1] = Account_numb.Text.ToString();
            row[2] = account_nam.Text.ToString();
            row[3] = owner.Text;
            row[4] = curency.Text.ToString();
            row[5] = date.ToString();
            row[6] = curncyval.Text;
            row[7] = note.Text;
            row[8] = Depet.Text;
            row[9] = criedt.Text;
            row[10] = Total_depet.Text;
            row[11] = Total_credit.Text;
            row[12] = Details.Text;
            row[13] = "false";
            dtab.Rows.InsertAt(row, index);
            dataGridView1.DataSource = dtab;
            dataGridView1.DataSource = dtab;
            DialogResult dialogResult = MessageBox.Show("تريد أدخال سجل أخر؟", "Some Title", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo);
            if (dialogResult == DialogResult.Yes)
            {

                row[0] = numb.Text.ToString();
                row[1] = Account_numb.Text.ToString();
                row[2] = account_nam.Text.ToString();
                row[3] = owner.Text;
                row[4] = curency.Text.ToString();
                row[5] = date.ToString();
                row[6] = curncyval.Text;
                row[7] = note.Text;
                row[8] = Depet.Text;
                row[9] = criedt.Text;
                row[10] = Total_depet.Text;
                row[11] = Total_credit.Text;
                row[12] = Details.Text;
                row[13] = "false";


                numb.Clear();
                owner.Clear();
                Account_numb.Text = "    ";
                account_nam.Text = "      ";
                curency.Text = "       ";
                curncyval.Clear();
                Total_credit.Clear();
                Total_depet.Clear();
                note.Clear();
                Details.Clear();
                criedt.Clear();
                Depet.Clear();




                return showout2(++index, true);
            }
            else if (dialogResult == DialogResult.No)
            {
                return dtab;
            }
        }
```

Comment: I edite the code it seem like the repeating of binding the DGV make it disappear

Comment: after editing your problem solved or not?

Comment: the DGV show the data but when I the dialogreslut shown the data cleared and also yes only repreating the dialog

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't understand what exactly the problem is but its seems that you are trying to add rows to datagridview and after added new row you ask the user "if he wan't to add more ?"

you first need to initialize the datagridview once ,when application load or in constructor.

```
  public void initDatagrid()
        {
            dataGridView1.Columns.Add(new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn { HeaderText = "رقم المتسلسل" });
            dataGridView1.Columns.Add(new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn { HeaderText = "رقم الحساب" });
            dataGridView1.Columns.Add(new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn { HeaderText = "أسم الحساب" });
            dataGridView1.Columns.Add(new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn { HeaderText = "المالك" });
            dataGridView1.Columns.Add(new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn { HeaderText = "تاريخ" });
            dataGridView1.Columns.Add(new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn { HeaderText = "قيمة" });
            dataGridView1.Columns.Add(new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn { HeaderText = "نوع العملة" });
            //...
        }
```

and after that you call this function to add rows

```
public void showout2()
        {
            object[] newRow = new object[14];
            try
            {

                newRow[0] = "test";
                newRow[1] = "test";
                newRow[2] = "test";
                newRow[3] = "test";
                newRow[4] = "test";
                newRow[5] = "test";
                newRow[6] = "test";
                //...
                dataGridView1.Rows.Add(newRow);

                if (MessageBox.Show("تريد أدخال سجل أخر؟", "Some Title", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo) == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.Yes)
                {
                    //clear data here ..
                }

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

            }
        }
```

EX:

```
public yourClass()
{
            InitializeComponent();
            initDatagrid();
}

private void AddButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    showout2();
}
```

Comment: the problem of showing the DGV has fixed but the dialogResult still happenes

Comment: check this you can create the datatable after you finished from datagrid by using **dataGridView.Rows.Count** and foreach on datagrid

Comment: ok its works , but the dialogresult still stak I will delet it

Comment: dialogresult will access the if statement if you press "Yes" ,you can add **else** to catch "No" command

Comment: thank you I fix the second problem I delete `return showout2(++index, true);` it was the problem